# `ray up` only launches Docker container on head

Tags: distributed, ray

I am trying to use the [Ray](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library to launch runs on multiple remote machines with Docker. Per the docs, I use `ray up CONFIG_YAML` to set up my cluster and `ray submit [OPTIONS] CLUSTER_CONFIG_FILE SCRIPT` to run a script on them. The problem is that the process/container only launches on the head node and nothing runs on the workers.

Examining the source, `ray up CONFIG_YAML` calls the function [`create_or_update_cluster`](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/autoscaler/commands.py#L34) and `ray submit [OPTIONS] CLUSTER_CONFIG_FILE SCRIPT` calls [`submit`](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/scripts/scripts.py#L622). Neither of these appear to interact with any node except the head.

Here is my Dockerfile: https://github.com/lobachevzky/ppo/blob/debug/Dockerfile

Here is my cluster config file: https://github.com/lobachevzky/ppo/blob/debug/tune.yaml

Here is my script: https://github.com/lobachevzky/ppo/blob/debug/tune_script.py

Comment: Hi Ethan; can you make an issue on github?

Comment: No problem. https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/5496